# c#: how to read CSV file with multiple elements per line and put in array?/ Why doesn't Split() work?

Tags: c#, arrays, csv, split, element

So a searched for a solution to this and some people have already asked but I wasn't sure if their answers would work for me? I copied this code and pasted it to one of my class's constructor:

```
var Lines = File.ReadLines("C:\\Users\\k20\\Source\\Repos\\TS_Webform\\TS_Webform\\Forms\\emails.csv").Select(a => a.Split(';'));
var CSV = from line in Lines select (line.Split(',')).ToArray(); //error on "Split"
```

I get this error message:

> "Error CS1061  'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Split' and no extension method 'Split' accepting a first argument of type 'string[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

When writing to my csv file, the first line is skipped entirely and then line 2 and onward will have 5 elements written as such: `example@example.com,example,15555555555,1234567890,1234567890`
every addition is like this. I'm not sure how the first skipped line will affect my code.

Comment: On the first line, try replacing `var` with the actual type and you'll see what's wrong...(hint: `Lines` is an `IEnumerable<string[]>`, not an `IEnumerable<string>`, because you're calling `Split(';')` at the end)

Comment: Each line you got is string[] not string because you have done split in your Select(a => a.Split(';'))

Answer (score 2):

As I pointed out in the comment, `Lines` is an `IEnumerable<string[]>`, not an `IEnumerable<string>`, because you're calling `Split(';')` at the end.

To resolve this, you can either use `SelectMany`, which will capture all the items from your first `Split(';')` and add them to the `Lines` list:

```
var Lines = File
    .ReadLines(@"C:\Users\k20\Source\Repos\TS_Webform\TS_Webform\Forms\emails.csv")
    .SelectMany(a => a.Split(';'));
```

Or, if you know you want just the first item, for example, from the original split, then you could select it using index syntax (`[0]`):

```
var Lines = File
    .ReadLines(@"C:\Users\k20\Source\Repos\TS_Webform\TS_Webform\Forms\emails.csv")
    .Select(a => a.Split(';')[0]);
```

Also, consider using a library, like [File Helpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/) for parsing CSV files. `Split` can cause some issues if you aren't sure about the contents of the file.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are already calling split once before on your first line:

```
var Lines = 
    File
    .ReadLines("C:\\Users\\k20\\Source\\Repos\\TS_Webform\\TS_Webform\\Forms\\emails.csv")
    .Select(a => a.Split(';')); // <--- This is causing your problem.
```

So `Lines` is an `IEnumerable<string[]>`. You then try to enumerate over each `string[]` and call `Split` on it but `string[]` has no such function.

In general this is a naive approach to parsing a CSV file. What happens if one of the values contains a comma:

> "e.g., like this"

In this case you would end up splitting your value. You know your data so you may be able to say with certainty that this will not be an issue. If so great. If not I would check NuGet for an existing package that can help you with this.

## Update

Based on your comments this may suffice:

```
var csv =
    File
    .ReadLines("C:\\Users\\k20\\Source\\Repos\\TS_Webform\\TS_Webform\\Forms\\emails.csv")
    .Select(line => line.Split(','))
    .ToArray();
```

After this `csv` will by type `string[][]`. But as I said, if you suspect that your values may contain commas this will not be sufficient. Check one of [these](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=csv) NuGet packages.

Comment: so I should just delete it?

Comment: @KevinSerrano - Well, like I said, if you know for sure that this will not be an issue then fantastic. Even if you suspect this might be an issue you should still be able to tidy up some of the edge cases (maybe not with LINQ alone). Otherwise, check NuGet. By the way, why are you splitting on ';' in the first line?

Comment: I just copied that code, I have no clue what's going on with it. I don't know what select(a=>a.Split(',')) I assume it's like using a delimiter in java or what "from line in Lines" does. I just thought I'd replace what isn't applicable to what does apply to me.

Comment: @KevinSerrano - Okay, ditch it then. You would only need that if you needed to split lines on ';' before then splitting on ','. Check my update, that may work for you.